# Increase the quota for Youtube v3

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, quota

I'm a developer of a program for streamers. It receives and displays various information, such as chat, super chat, sponsors. The problem is that at the moment the program is close to the limit. And this despite the fact that I increased the delay between requests, but it did not help, because every day there are new users.

[image: Screenshot]

How can I increase the quota for Youtube v3?

Comment: If not already implemented, you should also be caching API data locally. Depending on your request diversity, this might save you quite some quota.

Answer (score 1):

Check this [quota request page](https://services.google.com/fb/forms/ytapiquotarequest/) for Youtube API. You'll be required to answer several questions:

> This application also requires you to submit screenshots and design
>   documents relating to your API Client(s) and your use of YouTube
>   API(s). If you do not have these ready, please apply once these are
>   available.